# Cannot send push notifications to phonegap app via node terminal

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

I'm following the official phonegap docs to send a push notification to phonegap, but it gives me a syntax error.

> C:\Users\Claudio\Desktop\apps\myApp>phonegap push --deviceID  --service gcm --payload '{ "data": { "title": "Hello", "message": "World"} }'
>   undefined:1
>   '{
>   ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at PushCommand.execute (C:\Users\Claudio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\push.js:76:23)
>       at PushCommand.run (C:\Users\Claudio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\push.js:54:8)
>       at PhoneGap.push (C:\Users\Claudio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\util\command.js:28:25)
>       at CLI.module.exports [as push] (C:\Users\Claudio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\cli\push.js:27:12)
>       at CLI.module.exports [as argv] (C:\Users\Claudio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\cli\argv.js:128:17)
>       at runPhoneGapCommand (C:\Users\Claudio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js:31:9)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Claudio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js:23:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

Answer (score 1):

I followed another tutorial that instead escape the " character, using this command instead:

```
phonegap push --deviceID <ID> --service gcm --payload "{ \"data\":{ \"title\": \"Hello\", \"message\": \"World\"} }"
```

and it worked.

Although I still don't understand why the one proposed by the official phonegap app didn't. Maybe it addresses a different OS or terminal?